# Creating a formula to avoid dragging down without using (=array)

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I have three formulas

(1) =(B2:B&"."&substitute(substitute(lower(C2:C),"jalan","jln")," ",""))

(2) =COUNTIF('Payment Configuration'!A:A,A2:A) + COUNTIF('Payment Configuration'!E:E,A2:A)

(3) = =IF(ISBLANK(B:B),,B:B & ", " & UPPER(C:C) & ", BANDAR PUTERI KLANG")

Guys, I want to dragging this formula's until the last row without using Array formula because if I convert this formulas into array somehow it is not working in my web app (which is written in Google App Script). So anyone can help me with this formulas. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you want them to only work on a line at a time you need to trim the range to one row only:

`=(B2&"."&substitute(substitute(lower(C2),"jalan","jln")," ",""))`

`=COUNTIF('Payment Configuration'!A:A,A2) + COUNTIF('Payment Configuration'!E:E,A2)`

`=IF(ISBLANK(B2),,B2 & ", " & UPPER(C2) & ", BANDAR PUTERI KLANG")`

With the first two, you could add `ISBLANK` like your 3rd example.